# hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins, I'm trying to check out a pull request using a Groovy pipeline script:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
        branches: [[name: "origin/pr/${pullRequestId}/merge"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
        extensions: [], gitTool: 'jgit', submoduleCfg: [],
        userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: credentials,
                             name: 'origin', refspec: '+refs/pull-requests/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*',
                             url: repository]]])
```

The problem is that sometimes this works and sometimes I get the following error:

```
Exception is: hudson.AbortException: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
```

And the following stack trace:

```
  [hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:1002),
    hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1098),
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:109),
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:83),
     org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:73),
        org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47),
hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:260),
        org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44),
        java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511), java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266),
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142),
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)]
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: which git server do you use?

Comment: Is pullRequestId defined for every attempt? If it's empty it may point to an invalid branch...